# Translate simple jQuery selector to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a little trouble translating this simple piece of jQuery to Javascript. Can you help me with the correct syntax, i'm quite new to js.

```
jQuery('.navigation .select-menu option[value*="example-text"]').show();
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation .select-menu option[value*="example-text"]');
[].forEach.call(a, function (elem) {
    elem.style.display = '';
});
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` doesn't return an array; what it returns doesn't have `forEach`. And blindly setting `display: block` is quite a bad idea.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Corrected that!

Comment: Note the second part of the comment.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, What would you suggest as a better practice ?

Comment: @RayonDabre: Assigning a blank string works well, restoring the default. Alternately, assign the correct default (`inline`, `inline-block`, ...).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Agreed!!